# How to read specific frames from a video using OpenCV's Cuda Video Reader in Python?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, video

I've compiled OpenCV 4.8.0 with Cuda 10.2, cudNN 7.6.5.32, Video_Codec_SDK_12.1.14, and am running it on Python 3.9.13. I'm trying to read specific frames from a video file (video.mkv) using OpenCV's Cuda Video Reader, similar to how I would with the CPU-based VideoCapture.

Here's how I would do it using VideoCapture:

```py
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, target_frame)
```

For Cuda Video Reader, I currently have this code working:

```py
video_reader = cv2.cudacodec.createVideoReader('video.mkv')
fps_received, fps = video_reader.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
total_frames_received, total_frames = video_reader.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
for second in range(1, int(total_frames // fps) + 1):
    target_frame = int(second * fps)
    # TODO: Read only the target_frame and skip the rest
```

I consulted the [VideoReader API Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/db/ded/classcv_1_1cudacodec_1_1VideoReader.html) and attempted to use the [set()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/db/ded/classcv_1_1cudacodec_1_1VideoReader.html#aa0b71fd98fa3bce1f3bd834c8679ff1b) method, in which I can pass a [VideoReaderPropertys](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d0/d61/group__cudacodec.html#ga1ad08d8369c460158ad361779fab4753). The only property that made sense to me was the PROP_DECODED_FRAME_IDX which is described as "Index for retrieving the decoded frame using retrieve()."

```
set_success = video_reader.setVideoReaderProps(propertyId=0, propertyVal=target_frame) #PROP_DECODED_FRAME_IDX
print(set_success) # This is always False
has_frame, frame = video_reader.nextFrame()
```

1. How can I read a specific frame in a video using the Cuda Video Reader?
2. Is there a property similar to CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES for the Cuda version?

Comment: Why the C++ tag?

Comment: Its not really c++ or python specific if a guy knows the answer using c++ i can use the same thing in python. Thats why, i guess @molbdnilo

Comment: browse the opencv forum. I remember stuff like this (decoding video with cuda) was discussed there before. -- seeking in a video is a complicated operation. cuda video reader may not be intended for that. please explain your understanding video compression related to seeking.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-read-specific-frames-from-a-video-using-opencvs-cuda-video-reader-in-python/14698